# when running the same code the result are not consistent

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

so I've been trying to learn puppeteer, but when running this code I sometimes get the result I wanted, and sometimes I get back an empty array.
what am I missing?

```
const tutorial = async () => {
  try {
    const URL =
      "https://www.amazon.com/stores/page/947C6949-CF8E-4BD3-914A-B411DD3E4433/search?channel=discovbar%3Ffield-lbr_brands_browse-bin%3DAmazonBasics&ref_=nav_cs_amazonbasics&terms=tech";
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

 
    await page.goto(URL);
    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let results = [];
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".ProductGridItem__item__IkSDt");
      items.forEach((item) => {
        const dec = item.querySelector(".Price__fractional__wJiJp").innerText;
        const price = item.querySelector(".Price__whole__mQGs5").innerText;
        const fullPrice = `${price}.${dec}`;

        results.push({
          price: fullPrice,
          title: item.querySelector(".Title__fixed__bJ2c2").innerText,
        });
      });
      return results;
    });

    console.log(data);
    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

tutorial();
```

Comment: The code that it runs on the page works just fine every time, so I would think it's something with the loading of the page, and for some reason the code would run before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: how can i assure the code runs only after the page is fully loaded? I've tried with waitforxpath or waitfornavigation but it is still sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: You can maybe try wrapping it in a 
`document.onreadystatechange = () => {
     if (document.readystate = "complete") {
            // code
     }
}`